# Hibernate JPA Annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa

why I need to provide the entity name in hibernate configuration file while I have already marked an class as entity.I am not able to persist data without that mapping XML tag in hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: You don't need any hibernate.cfg.xml file to use Hibernate as a JPA provider. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_jpa, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JPA 2.1 specification:

> A list of all named managed persistence classes must be specified in
>   **Java SE environments** to insure portability.

Otherwise, if you are using Spring Boot, you can do so by using the `@EntityScan` annotation. You can use the `basePackages` attribute and point to one or many packages to include when scanning for entities without the need of `persistence.xml` anymore.